# unix find filenames that are lexicographically less that a given filename

Tags: regex, shell, unix, find

I have a list of files in a directory that are automatically generated by a system with the date in the filename. Some examples are: `audit_20111020`, `audit_20111021`, `audit_20111022`, etc.

I want to clean up files older than 18 months therefore I want to put together a unix find command that will find files less than `audit_20100501` and delete them.

Does any know how to use lexicographical order as a criteria in the find command?

Answer (score 2):

Another Perl variant:

```
perl -E'while(<audit_*>) { say if /(\d{8})/ && $1 < 20100501}'
```

Replace `say` by `unlink` if it prints expected filenames.

Note: `<` performs numerical comparison, use `lt` if you want string comparison.

Answer (score 1):

With Perl it's easy. Type `perl` and:

```
for (glob "*")
{
  my($n) = /(\d+)/;
  unlink if ($n < 20100501);
}
^D
```

Test before using. Note that I'm assuming this is a fixed format and the directory only contains these files

Comment: it is safer to use "audit_*".

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to sort `find`'s result using the `sort` command:

```
find . -name "audit*" | sort -n
```

... then find a way to split this list.

---

But for what you want to do, i.e. delete directories older than a certain date (18 months is ~547 days), you could use the below instead:

```
find -ctime -547 -type d | xargs -I{} rm -rf {}
```